# Handle jwt expiration in SPA

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, jwt

The beckend give me a JWT where even the public key is encrypted, the only thing that i have is the jwt encoded.

I append the jwt in all my http calls, the problem is that my app have only 5 http calls, where 4 are get and only 1 is a put. My problem is that I can check the validity of the token only on the first 4 http call and after all the data is cached, so i can't control anymore the validity of the token. How can i watch the expiration date and automatically logout the user when the token is invalid? should I make a interval where I check every tot minute the token validity on a specific endpoint? Like:

The token expires in 3 hours, so i check every 20 minute the token validity with a ping to the server

Answer (score 0):

Multiple solutions for your problem :

- Ask the backend team to return you the token's expiration date along with the token.
- The token is just a base64 encode string, you can decode it and extract the expiration date stored in it.

Comment: The backend send me the token expiration in a json file

Comment: Well since you have the expiration, what's the issue? Just request a new token before the expiration date